# Dynamically increase and decrease numbers in JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I would like to know how to dynamically increase and decrease numbers in JavaScript.
The users buys an item and I have a input field "quantity" with a number and two buttons: One to add and another to remove.

My code is the following

```
<td class="quantity">
    <a href="#" class="removeItem">-</a>
    <input type="text" id="purchase_quantity" min="1" max="99" delta="0" cost="<?php echo$poupa ?>" name="purchase_quantity" value="1" />
    <a href="#" class="addItem" >+</a>
</td>
```

How can I have it decrease the number of the input field when I click on the "-" and increase the number of the input field when clicking on the "+"?

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = document.getElementById("YOUR_INPUT_ID");

function minus(){
  var num = +input.value;//+ for convert from string to number
  num--;
  input.value = num;
}

function plus(){
  var num = +input.value;//+ for convert from string to number
  num++;
  input.value = num;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VY9tE/

One more example with your html form and with check count(0..99):

http://jsfiddle.net/VY9tE/2/

Comment: Now i would like to multiple the value of minus or plus to a value of input i have. I have the following code:                           <tr>
 <th class="totalLabel"  colspan="2" >Total</th>
                                <?php echo("<th class='totalPrice'  colspan='3' id='totalPrice'>$poupa €</th>"); ?>
                            </tr>

Comment: I think you don't understand my question.....I have a fixed price and i have a total.I need to multiply the fixed price with the quantity_purchase like...if my quantity is 2 and my price is 20€..the result will be 40€.I have a input field to get the fixed price like      <tr> <th class="totalLabel" colspan="2" >Total</th> <?php echo("<th class='totalPrice' colspan='3' id='totalPrice'>$poupa €</th>"); ?> </tr> and i need to change this fixed price to a new price when the users choose the quantity

Answer (score 0):

decrease:

```
<a href="#" class="removeItem" onclick="$('#purchase_quantity').val($('#purchase_quantity').val()-1); return false;">-</a>
```

increase

```
<a href="#" class="addItem" onclick="$('#purchase_quantity').val($('#purchase_quantity').val()+1); return false;">+</a>
```

Assuming you can use jquery since you have it tagged.

Answer (score 0):

Markup (changed the ID on the text input to a class):

```
<td class="quantity">
    <a href="#" class="removeItem">-</a>
    <input type="text" class="purchase_quantity" min="1" max="99" delta="0" cost="" name="purchase_quantity" value="1" />
    <a href="#" class="addItem">+</a>
</td>
```

JavaScript (uses jQuery):

```
$(function() {
    $('.removeItem').click(function() {
        // Find the appropriate quantity input
        var target = $(this).siblings('.purchase_quantity');

        // Get the current quantity
        var currentQuantity = $(target).val();

        // Not allowed to go below zero
        if (currentQuantity > 0) {
            // Update input with decreased quantity    
            $(target).val(--currentQuantity);
        }
    });

    $('.addItem').click(function() {
        // Find the appropriate quantity input
        var target = $(this).siblings('.purchase_quantity');

        // Get the current quantity
        var currentQuantity = $(target).val();

        // Update input with increased quantity    
        $(target).val(++currentQuantity);
    });
});
```

[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/64UcJ/4).