# how to increase and decrease the value of range slider input on clicking next and prev button (vanilla JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

this is the code
How to increase/ decrease value by 20?

```
<div class="slider">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="0" class="img__slider" id="myRange">
</div>

<div>
    <button id="prev">Prev</button>
    <button id="next">Next</button>
</div>
```

js code

```
const prevbtn = document.querySelector('#prev');
const nextbtn = document.querySelector('#next');
const rangeValue = document.querySelector('#myRange');

nextbtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let getValue = rangeValue.value;

  getValue += 20
})

prevbtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let getValue = rangeValue.value;

  getValue -= 20
})
```

I tried increasing the value on click but it doesnt work

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what research you've done and what attempts you've made to solve this issue yourself. See [ask] for more tips on the steps you can follow to avoid downvotes and close votes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically increase and decrease numbers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17958363/dynamically-increase-and-decrease-numbers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method :

```
const prevbtn = document.querySelector('#prev');
const nextbtn = document.querySelector('#next');
const rangeValue = document.querySelector('#myRange');

nextbtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  rangeValue.setAttribute('value', rangeValue.value + 20)
})

prevbtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  rangeValue.setAttribute('value', rangeValue.value - 20)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use step attribute

```
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="0" step="20"class=" img__slider" id="myRange">
</div>

<div>
    <button>Prev</button>
    <button>Next</button>
</div>
```